# Is potential enough to determine dipole distribution?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, dipole

I was working on a problem and I had to mathematically distinguish a charge and its distribution from a dipole and its distribution in the space. Following is an example where I am confused how to find the dipole distribution by thetotal electric potential
of the system.

Suppose there exists a dipole at the origin, **p** = p**i**, in the plane and the potential of the system is given by the $\text{V} = \frac{\text{kp}\cos(\phi)}{r^2}$.

Taking the laplacian gives $\nabla^2\text{V} = \frac{3\text{kp}\cos(\phi)}{r^4}$ which is not the distribution of the charge (since a pure dipole is not a charge)

Specifically, I was trying to solve for the potential of a system given a dipole in the system, and from a mathematical point of view, I couldn't paraphrase the system in terms of some PDE. e.g, for the above situation how to write a PDE with some boundary conditions so that its solution is uniquely that of a dipole at the origin.
To compare, if I said laplacian is $q\delta^3(x,y,z)$ on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$ and at infinity is zero, I think the solution is the field of a charge at the origin.

Comment: The field of a charge distribution can be modeled as a multipole expansion, but I don't believe that it is mathematically useful to ask what the equivalent dipole distribution for a given charge distribution is. Whenever we talk about physical dipoles, we mean actual charge distributions that have a dipole moment and for which we simply don't care about the higher multipole moments.

Comment: I am not asking about how to convert the charge distribution to dipole distribution. I was asking if i give you the potential, could you tell me that there is a dipole generating it?

Comment: If you have a dipole, then Gauss' Law gives you exactly two points in space around which the total flux through a surface around the point is non-zero. For every spatial volume that does not contain these points and for every volume that contains both the net flux is zero. The limit that these two points are the same is mathematically not well defined. These problems already happen in functions of a single variable: in general the local approximation requires an infinite number of derivatives and we can write down fairly trivial functions for which there is no Tayler expansion at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you made a mistake in your calculation. Taking the oppropriate expression of the [Laplacian](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) in spherical coordinates, and normalizing the dipole moment so that $p=e_z$, you’ll rather find that if (for $r\neq0$):
$$
V(r,\theta,\phi)=\frac{\cos\theta}{4\pi r^2}
$$
then (for $r\neq0$):
$$
\Delta V=0
$$
To include the origin, you’ll need distributions. You can check that:
$$
-\Delta V=-\partial_z\delta
$$
which shows unambiguously that it is the field generated by an ideal dipole. Note that it is consistent with the previous result.

Indeed, assuming Gauss’ law, you just need to know the charge density of an ideal dipole. As you pointed out, a single monopole would have charge density:
$$
\rho(x)=q\delta(x)
$$
So a real dipole has charge density:
$$
\rho(x)=q\delta(x-d)-q\delta(x)
$$
The ideal dipole is obtained by taking the limit $d\to0$, $q\to\infty$ while keeping $qd=p$ giving:
$$
\rho(x)=-p\cdot \nabla\delta(x)
$$

Hope this helps.